# IF, Match & VLOOKUP?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this case where I manually will write add data in column A and B. I want Excel to match column A and D and return the corresponding value from Column B in the right row in Column E.
As an Example, then Excel should write 82 in Cell E3, 29 in Cell E19 etc.
Do you have any idea of how to write this formula?

Please note that the input in Column A & B will vary from time to time. The list in Column D might also be longer at some point.

Thanks for your help! :)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9zbn.png)

Comment: Have you tried `VLOOKUP`. That should work. Add your formula to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)
```

Then drag the formula down.

In my example, I use the following formula (which includes an extra row)

```
=VLOOKUP(D2,$A$2:$B$7,2,FALSE)
```

`VLOOKUP` accepts the following parameters:

`VLOOKUP(Value to Lookup, Range to Search, Column To Return, Range Lookup)`

You usually want to set Range Lookup to `FALSE` or else it returns an "approximate match" which, in my experience, is rarely correct

> Range_lookup - a logical value that specifies whether you want the VLookup method to find an exact match or an approximate match:

The column to return in our case is column `2`.

If you use column `1`, it will return the name that it found.

The Range to Search is our "table" containing the data.

In your case it is `$A$2:$B$6`.

You can also highlight your table and give it a Named Range.

If you give it a named range, you can update the named range and you won't have to alter your formula.

If you name it, you can simply use the named range as the Range to Search.

Example: `=VLOOKUP(D2,MyNamedRange,2,False)`

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks - Just what I was looking for! :)